# Proving every open subset $H$ of the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ is the union of open discs

Tags: general-topology

I am going through the proof of

> Every open subset $H$ of the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ is the union of open discs

in a book (open disc is the standard open Euclidean disc or open ball). It goes like this:

Since $H$ is open, for each point $p \in H$ there is an open disc $E_{p}$ such that $p \in E_{p} \subset H$.(I agree with this statement).

Now it tells $H = \bigcup\{E_{p} : p \in H\}$. This I did not understand. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof:** To see it, firstly let us prove that $H \subseteq \bigcup \{E_p: p\in H\}$. Since for any $p\in H$, there exists $E_p$ such that $p \in E_p \subseteq \bigcup \{E_p: p\in H\}$.

Then we prove $\bigcup \{E_p: p\in H\}\subseteq H$. It is not difficult to see it is true since each $E_p\subseteq H$. This complete the proof.

---

**Another idea:**

Notice all the open discs forms a base of $\Bbb R^2$. Then by the definition of topology, we can conclude that every open set is a union of open discs.

Answer (score 2):

$H\subset \bigcup \{E_p: p\in H\}$ since $p\in E_p \forall p\in H$. For the other direction, note $E_p\subset H$, so $\bigcup \{E_p: p\in H\}\subset H$.